Gaetz, correct German pronunciation: Gates, or Gets?
Gaetz, correct German pronunciation: Gates, or Gets ?

Is this supposed to be a family name?

Last name: Gaetz

If this is about Matt Gaetz, the correct German pronunciation can be found at the top of the Wikipedia article.

There are several people with the last name "Gaetz" listed in Wikipedia, but they're all either American or Canadian, so I don't think you can say it's a German name anymore and therefore has no "correct" German Pronunciation. Perhaps it was originally German, probably some variant of "Gätz". There is a photographer, Phillip Gätz, based in Hamburg, so that name isn't unknown in Germany, but it seems to be relatively rare. In any case, Google translate gives a reasonably accurate German pronunciation of anything you type into it, though native German speakers might be able fine tune it a bit.

For foreign person names, we try not not change the pronunciation to German (inside the limits of our skills and being understandable), so for Matt Gaetz, who is American, the "German pronunciation" is the American English pronunciation (/ɡeɪts/). Same for Donald Trump, Joni Ernst, Mike Braun etc.
If you assume that Gaetz is a German name and want to use the German pronunciation for some reason, I can say that I would pronounce it with a long Ä, like "Gates", but with the vowel being more like in "gas" or "jazz": /ɡæts/.
@RHa would pronounce it with a short Ä, like "gets" (see comments). There definitely is a much more common name "Götz" that is prononced with a short Ö.

I would say "Gets" is pretty close to how a German would pronounce "Gätz".

@RHa: interesting, I added that.

There is no "German" pronunciation. One of the differences between German and (American) English is the way words and names from foreign languages are pronounced. In English it is considered to be pretentious to use a pronunciation of words that tries to imitate the original language. In German, it is considered to be a a proof of good education to be able to pronounce words as close to their language of origin as possible.
